# use a global variable in different files

Tags: c

So what i'm trying to do is using a variable from file1.c in file2.c.
I've seen some answers already on here but I still get the same error as before. (`error: variably modified at file scope`)

What I have on file1.c is something like this:

```
extern int num = 0;
struct abc *do_something(int n){
    num = n;
}
/*more code below*/
```

now I wanted to use `num` on file2.c. I have this:

```
#include <something.h> /*which has file1.h inside*/
int num;
struct list_t list[num]; /*error here*/

/*code that uses the initialized list below*/
```

I tried using something like `#define test_num num` that it didn't work either. I need the list to be "global" on file2 so I can use it in different methods.

Comment: Do not use global  variables. Usually ends in tesrs

Comment: @EdHeal : Was that "tasers" or "tears"?  I really hope "tasers" ;-)

Comment: There is a comment that mentions file1.h, but no file1.h mentioned in the question.

Comment: Bloody phone it is tears

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems actually. The first which relates to your error is that the value of `num` is *unknown* when the compiler sees the declaration of your array `list`. The compiler doesn't know anything from any other [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (a source file with all included header files), all it knows is the translation unit it's currently working on.

The second problem is more theoretical, and it's that the size of an array is fixed at the time of compilation, and changing the variable `num` at run-time will not change the size of the array.

The first problem can be solved by moving the initialization of `num` to the [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) where it actually is used. Oh and not initialize it as zero, a zero-sized array is not of much use.

The second problem can be solved by using pointers and dynamic allocation using `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: Hi, I do need/want the size of the array to be the same. But about the issue of `num` to be unknown I thought that by initializing it on file 1 and changing before it being used on file2 it would solve the problem. I'll check out your link ty.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the `list` declaration is nothing to do with the definition of the global `num`, although that is also incorrect, but rather that you are attempting to dimension an array with with a variable outside of a function.  Which is illegal and also nonsense.  The value of `num` when `list` is instantiated is non-deterministic, and even if `num` were were initialised first, you'd be declaring an array of zero length.

You have the `extern` in the wrong place.  In file1.c you should have:

```
int num = 0 ;
```

while in file2.c:

```
extern int num ;
```

Normally you would place the `extern` declaration in a header file - this allows the compiler to check the types match between declaration and definition, and allows the correct and consistent declaration to be used in multiple files with a single point of maintenance should you change the type for example.

```
// file1.h
#if !defined file1_INCLUDE
#define file1_INCLUDE

extern int num ;  // Declaration

#endif
```

---

```
// file1.c
#include "file1.h"

int num = 0 ; // Definition/Instantiation
```

---

```
// file2.c
#include "file1.h"
int f()
{
    return num ;  // Use file1::num
}
```

All that said *really* don't use globals at all.  It is bad practice and unnecessary.  Rather:

```
// file1.h
#if !defined file1_INCLUDE
#define file1_INCLUDE

  void setNum( int n ) ;
  int getNum() ;

#endif
```

---

```
// file1.c
#include "file1.h"

static int num = 0 ; // Protected by file scope
void setNum( int n ) { num = n ; }
int getNum() { return n ; }
```

---

```
// file2.c
#include "file1.h"

int f()
{
    setNum( getNum() + 1 ) ;  // Increment num (example r/w access)
    return getNum() ;
}
```

This has a number of advantages, including:

- The set function can range check or validate
- A variable may be made read-only by external functions (by omitting a setter)
- A variable may be made write-only by external functions (by omitting a getter)
- Nothing can take a reference to the variable and monkey with it in an uncontrolled manner.
- In debug all accesses to the variable can be trapped by break-points in the access functions.

Further reading [A Pox on Globals](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) (related to embedded systems, but no less applicable generally.

Answer (score 0):

To share a global variable between two files you should be aware that the variable belongs to the source file which has it declared without "extern". As such, it should also be initialized in that source file. Using extern tells your compiler it will find the variable from some other object file at link time.

As Joachim wrote you also have a problem with your array using this global variable.